# How I can start a PDF File in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, webserver, pdf-reader

hi I want to Open a PDF file in asp.net. For my example I want that if I user click on help button a method call `OpenPdfFile()` start. This Method load a pdf file in a PdfReader object and then I want to save this pdf in a new file on temp flder on my webserver. then must open this document and I the user close this then must the document delete from the temp folder.

Or.

I want only load the pdf in my pdfreader object and start them.

here is my code:

```
string oldfile = Server.MapPath(@"~/App_Data/layout.pdf");
string newfile = Path.GetTempPath() + "gastzugang_" + visit + ".pdf";    
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(oldfile);
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you want to do? What is this `PdfReader` class supposed to do?

It just seems like you want to show a PDF file to the user. Use `Response.TransmitFile(oldfile)`, no need to read, copy and delete and read the file serverside.

Comment: How can you use what?

Comment: That is no JavaScript.